# Google Calendar API causing HTTP Error 500

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm using the new Google Calendar API v3. I'm trying to obtain the users calendar list using the PHP library. If I make the request directly using CURL then it works fine, but for some reason when I try and use the PHP library it fails and throws a 500 error. 
Here's the (abbreviated) code:

```
 $this->calendarAPI = new apiCalendarService($this->client);
 $calendar_list = $this->calendarAPI->calendarList->list();
```

If I var_dump the contents of $this->calendarAPI->calendarList then I get an object as I would expect. It's only when I call the list method that everything goes wrong.

Can anyone help or am I going to have to write my own library and interact with the API protocol directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so it turns out this is a mistake in the docs. Instead of calling a method called list() you have to call listCalendarList() so the second line should be:

```
 $calendar_list = $this->calendarAPI->calendarList->listCalendarList();
```